# Warum "das" in "ein Haus an das Ufer bauen"?

Tags: grammar, preposition, grammatical-case

Aus der [Süddeutschen Zeitung](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/kultur/wende-museum-in-kalifornien-sandmaennchen-am-silver-lake-1.2201079):

> Bevor wir zu der Hauptperson dieser Geschichte kommen, erst einmal kurz zu dem österreichischen Architekten Richard Neutra: Das Haus, das der sich 1932 in Los Angeles **an das Ufer** des Silver Lake gebaut hatte und das nach einem Brand in den Sechzigern von Neutras Sohn leicht verändert wiedererrichtet wurde, steht Freunden der frühen kalifornischen Moderne heute an den Wochenenden zur andächtigen Besichtigung frei.

Hier sind zwei Beispiele vom [Reverso Wörterbuch](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/ufer):

> direkt am Ufer gelegen
>
> etw ans Ufer spülen

Beide Beispiele sind klar: **etw ans Ufer spülen** beschreibt eine Bewegung Richtung Ufer, und **direkt am Ufer gelegen** deutet, dass sich etwas am Ufer befindet.

Aber was ist mit **das Haus an das Ufer bauen**? Hier hat man keine Bewegung Richtung Ufer (oder ich hoffe zumindest nicht). Warum denn der Akkusativ **das Ufer**?

Comment: I would say there is a movement/direction: you take the (not yet existing) house from its place on the drawing board, or your imagination, and move it onto the riverside my building it there. And physically you're moving lorries and bricks and other building materials thither.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die zwei Möglichkeiten

> am Ufer bauen
>   ans Ufer bauen

drücken zwei verschiedene Apekte aus, etwa vergleichbar mit

> am Ufer ein Ei legen
>   ans Ufer ein Ei legen

Nach ersterem kann mit *Wo?*, nach zweiterem mit *Wohin?* gefragt werden.

Der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Varianten

> Das Haus, das der sich 1932 in Los Angeles am Ufer des Silver Lake gebaut hatte [...]
>   Das Haus, das der sich 1932 in Los Angeles an das Ufer des Silver Lake gebaut hatte [...]

ist gering: Die Wahl von *an das* lässt den Bauvorgang einfach/schnell erscheinen, so wie "etwas irgendwo hintun" - zack, und da ist es/war es dann. Damit rückt der Bauvorgang in den Hintergrund, und die Ortswahl in den Vordergrund (passend zum Kontext). Carsten gibt eine intuitiv sehr treffende Beschreibung.

Answer (score 1):

Wie Cerberus schon in seinem Kommentar schreibt, wird hier der Akkusativ benutzt, weil ausgedrückt wird, dass das Haus vorher nicht am(!) Ufer war, hinterher aber schon.  Möchte man hingegen den Vorgang des Bauens und nicht das Ergebnis betonen, so kann man auch sagen, dass das Haus am Ufer gebaut wird: All die Bauarbeiter sind während des Baus am Ufer.

Comment: Ich seh da nichts im Originaltext von Bewegung oder ob es das Haus vorher schon mal woanders gegeben hat...

Comment: Ich habe ja auch nicht behauptet, dass das Haus vorher anderswo gewesen wäre.

Comment: Kann der Downvoter bitte erklären, welchen Teil er nicht verstanden hat?

Comment: Ja, das würde mich auch sehr interessieren. Die Antwort ist wie sie ist völlig ok und hat mit "vorher nicht da - danach schon" auch die Essenz getroffen. Warum also 2(!) downvotes??

Comment: Ich sehe ja ein, dass der Text etwas knapp ist und vielleicht verständlicher hätte sein können. Aber wenn das heißt, dass ich keine Antworten im Bett mit dem iPad schreiben sollte...  Well, whatever.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz What is perhaps not clear in your answer was how the movement was implied; however, that is explained in Cerberus' comment, and you did mention that. So I think it's perfectly fine. Just to clarify -- I wasn't one of the downvoters, and thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Es ist nicht irgendein Ufer, sondern das Ufer des Silver Lake: man baut etwas ans (= an das) Ufer; *am Ufer* wäre nicht falsch, bezieht sich dann aber auf den Bauvorgang.